# Multitasking in iphone

Tags: iphone, ipad, multitasking

How to implement the multitasking where to open the other application from my application (for example: opening my PDF document in to the iBooks app)?

Comment: This isn't multitasking that you're asking about, but custom document handling using either document types or custom URL schemes.

Answer (score 0):

See the documentation for `UIDocumentInteractionController`. It offers the functionality to give the user a preview of a document and present her with a list of apps in which she can open this document.

AFAIK it is not possible to send a PDF to iBooks programmatically without user interaction.